# What limits the number of operations in a block?

Tags: block

I see there is a [hard block gas limit](https://edo2net.tzkt.io/PtEdo2ZkT9oKpimTah6x2embF25oss54njMuPzkJTEi5RqfdZFA/constants), but is there any other limit? For example, is there any hard block storage limit, or a hard limit on the number of kB per block?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the hard gas limit, there's a limit on the size of the block (in bytes)<sup>[1](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/should-the-block-size-limit-be-folded-into-the-gas-limit/2143)</sup>. The maximum size of the list of operations in a block is 512kB<sup>[2](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_009_PsFLoren/lib_protocol/main.ml#L84)</sup>.